# Merge/rebase after directory reorganization

Tags: git

I have been working on a side-branch to rework the folder structure of a big repository that contains several projects.

While I was working on this rework, few of my team mates have modified the same folders I was working on. Since I never changed the actual content of the code files but only their position (100% rename) and the project files, I was expecting the changes to flow automatically into the new location.

Unluckily this is not the case and I understand I will need to solve those conflicts (3-way conflict) by hand but I wonder if there is a way to somehow automate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Git generally handles merges that it considers trivial enough for it to handle.  The fact that it can't indicates that there's not really an automated way to handle this; Git believes that your code base has changed drastically enough that you have to intervene.

Comment: Your title says both merge and rebase.  Which did you do?  Although git can be a little unintuitive at times, if expect a rebase in this situation to succeed.

Comment: @DanFarrell tried both, succeeded none. I'd prefer the clean history from a rebase, but I'd settle for a merge if it worked as it should.

Comment: @Makoto the problem is that I feel lost when I have to decide which course of action to take when for the files that are "deleted by them", "deleted by us", "deleted by both"...

Comment: Please provide the history of the git commands you performed so we can have a clearer idea of the state, thx ;)

Comment: @Kralizek Moo. The link to your website on your profile is dead :|

Comment: @NicolasCailloux as of now, nothing, I have tried a couple of times on freshly cloned repos so nothing to "repair".

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! Fixed the link :P